# Binder validator for field doesn't work properly for NullPresentation value

Tags: java, validation, vaadin, vaadin8

I have the following class:

```
public class FooClass {

        Integer number;

        String numberInLetters;

        public Integer getNumber() {
            return number;
        }

        public void setNumber(Integer number) {
            this.number = number;
        }

        public String getNumberInLetters() {
            return numberInLetters;
        }

        public void setNumberInLetters(String numberInLetters) {
            this.numberInLetters = numberInLetters;
        }
    }
```

When I set, for example, a simple binder for a field named **number**, associated to **fooObject**:

```
FooObject fooObject = new FooObject();
fooObject.setNumberInLetters("thirty");

IntegerRangeValidator validator = new IntegerRangeValidator("The value must be greater than or equal to 30", 30, null);
validator.setMinValueIncluded(true);

Binder<FooObject> binder = new Binder<>();
binder.forField(number)
                .withConverter(Integer::valueOf, String::valueOf, "Must be a number")
                .withNullRepresentation(0)
                .withValidator(intervaloValidator)
                .bind(FooObject::getNumber, Fooobject::setNumber);
```

The validator works as expected

- [image: error with one]
- [image: must be a number error]
- [image: validation succesfully]

Except when is zero (null representation), in this case, the validation doesn't work.

[image]

I can fix this, removing `withNullRepresentation(0)` but when I charge my form show `null` text, like this:

[image]
[image]

> How to validate Zero value when I put a null representation for the
>   field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vaadin [RangeValidator](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/data/validator/RangeValidator.java#L204) returns `true` when validating `null` value. When `null` presentation is `0` then user input `"0"` results `null` value which is valid for this validator.

You can fix this by implementing a validator that does *not* return `true` for `null` value.

Sometimes you will need to know difference between `null` and `0` values so then using a converter that converts `null` to `""` presentation instead of using `withNullPresentation(0)` will be useful.